# Link that forwards the URL's parameters

Tags: html, parameter-passing, url-parameters

There is a main Sales Page: site.com/sales-page

That page receives visitors from different traffic sources, and they are mentioned on its URL parameters, such as: site.com/sales-page?utm_source=fbads&utm_campaign=banner

That Sales Page has a link pointing to BUY NOW

How do I pass all URL parameters from the current window, such as "?utm_source=fbads&utm_campaign=banner" automatically to the next page via the BUY NOW button?

I need this so the Checkout page will know where the traffic came from, based on that forwarded parameter.

PS: I want to pass all parameters available in the URL, not just pre-defined ones.

PPS: Solution must work on most browsers and on static pages, better to not use cookies/php.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does "Buy now" do, is it just a link? Couldn't you just add the same query string to the end of that link and then read it on the next page?

Comment: Yes, just a link. How would I add it dynamically? The URL parameters are always changing, utm_source=fbads, utm_source=googleads, utm_source=pinterest, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to achieve this using HTML. You **have** to use a programming language.

For example:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://example.com/foo/?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
?>
<a href="<?= htmlspecialchars($url); ?>">link</a>
```

If you don't want to use PHP, then other programming languages are available.

Comment: My site is hosted on S3, so I can't use PHP. I think Javascript should work right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with just html. Best solution is serverside code. Fallback is to use JavaScript, but this will not work if JavaScript is disabled. You can read the search from the url and add it to your link.

```
<a id="buyNow" href="http://www.example.com">Buy</a>    
<script>
  (function () {
    var lnk = document.getElementById("buyNow");
    lnk.href = lnk.href + window.location.search;
  }())
</script>
```

This assumes there is no querystring already on the link. If there is, you need to replace the `?` in the search with a `&`

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!